# Marking overdue dates on excel (bit more complicated)

Tags: excel

I have already figured out (thanks to stackoverflow) how to add automatic due dates, and how to mark them using conditional formatting.

I have 3 columns, one ‘Status’ with options ‘Complete, Fail, Pending’. I have another column that automatically updates itself when a row is edited. And a 3rd column, with 15 days added to automatically updated column, which I call due date.

I want to make it so that if due date is passed when someone opens the workbook, the entire row is marked red or something. But I only want to do it for the Pending ones. If a row is marked Fail or Complete, it should not be marked red eventhough last time it was updated was weeks ago. How do i do it :(

Comment: A screenshot would go a long way here - but it sounds like conditional formatting is the way to go.

Comment: Use conditional formatting and your problem is solved. If you want to do something else please share the sample data

Comment: Conditional formatting with IF function, probably. Should I let it calculate due dates for everything, and then somehow only mark that are Pending AND Due, or should I set it to not calculate Due Date at all if a value in another column is Complete or Fail, and then use conditional formatting from the calculated dates, I do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format the overdue cell with a formula such as:

`=AND([status cell] = "Pending", [due cell] > TODAY())`

Quote below adapted from: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/

> - On the Home tab, click *Conditional Formatting menu > New Rule*.
> - Create    a new formatting rule based on a formula, as explianed in [How to    create Excel conditional formatting rules with a
>     formula](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/10/excel-conditional-formatting-formulas/#conditional-formatting-using-formulas).
> - In the    "Format values where this formula is true" box, enter the following formula
>
>   `=AND([status cell] = "Pending", [due cell] > TODAY())`
> - Click the Format… button and set up your    custom format by switching between the *Font*, *Border* and *Fill* tabs and    playing
>     with different formatting options. When done, click the *OK*    button
>     to preview the rule.
>
> [image: Entering Formatting Rules]

Comment: I tried to use conditional formatting on the due date column, and then write an IF function similar to this: IF Status= Pending AND due date>today. For some reason it did not work.

Comment: @kalinda94 Did you forget to put braces after `TODAY()`? Also, you'll need to put the conditions in braces after `AND` as in my answer.

Comment: Honestly, I just learned how to do IF today. Cant post s picture but here’s what I’m trying to do:A1 Status B1 Last updated C1 Due Date, A2 Complete B2 01/07/2017 C2 16/07/2017 A3 Pending B3 01/07/2017 C3 16/07/2017 Despite both being way overdue and exact same dates, I only want row 3 to be marked red

Comment: @kalinda94 Yeah I see what you're trying to do. The formula I posted should pretty much take care of that. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Am I supposed to use IF at the beginning of this? Nothing happens when i just use AND, and if I put an IF to the beginning it gives invalid formula.

Comment: IF(AND([A3] = "Pending", [B3] > TODAY())        this is what i'm trying

Comment: @kalinda94 Nah you don't need an `IF`. Check my answer for details.